# Solr: Sort by id desc for > 1000 items

Tags: solr, lucene

This feels weird, but I'm trying to search and sort on my id (primary) field with solr. I have a query like:

```
http://foo.com/solr/collection/select?q=*%3A*&sort=id+desc&fl=id+title&wt=json
```

This returns fields sorted in a descending order, but starting at 999. I have ~1200 items in my index.

From my schema.xml:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I did think about making my id an int, but I'd have to kill everything and start over (not a big issue tho).

Any tips?

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your id field is truly a numeric value and you want to sort by that value, I would recommend one of the following two options.

1. Change the field type to int and reindex.
2. Create a new field `id_sort` that is of type int and use the [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) directive to populate that field with the value from the `id` field at index time.